# PHP Error waiting on socket

Tags: centos, php, socket, netstat

I'm getting problems with ssh2 and fread php function that started on a few days.

On the apache error log show:

```
ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-9): Error waiting on socket 

fread(): Failure 'Error waiting on socket' (-9)
```

I'm searching for it on internet but have no success.

The server have much connections, maybe can be this?

```
# netstat -anp | wc -l
102407

# netstat -anp | grep TIME_WAIT -c
97444

# cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_count
263737
```

My sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
fs.file-max = 13143781
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 900000
net.nf_conntrack_max = 900000
net.core.wmem_max = 12582912
net.core.rmem_max = 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 5000
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 4096
net.core.somaxconn = 1024
```